# PostgreSQL active but not accepting connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Today morning, I have got a call from my manager that our clients are not able to log into the system and kinda thought it was just a small application failure or something like that. However when i got into the server and checked out, it turned out to be PostgreSQL problem.

Here is the case

I have checked with service Postgres status and it is showing the below results

[image: active]

And I have checked with netstat it does not show any active sessions and I wanted to connect through terminal and it showed the following error

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

The interesting part of this is that it was working just fine a day earlier, I even have checked it at midnight it was working but I have no idea what happened to Postgres all other things working fine. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect via TCP? `psql -h localhost -p 5432 ...`?

Comment: No i cannot connect via TCP it is saying no tcp connections @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: what could be the reason of working thing suddenly stop and not accepting any connections I do not understand @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Is any postgres process running on the system? If not, please check if an old postmaster.pid file still exists and delete the file.

Comment: logs log logs - don't guess and stumble around blindy, what do your logs say?

Comment: is it safe to delete postmaster.pid file ? @steve

Comment: where could i find logs of postgres I could not find any logs on the system @RichardHuxton

Comment: On unix-based systems you would start looking in /var/log/ for your logs

Comment: How did you install it?  Different installation methods choose different places to put the logs.  Plus you can configure it yourself to override the installation settings.

Comment: Guys thanks a lot I have resolved the issue it was because of the whole different thing our system got full -> root directory and it became even bigger issue. After hours of digging into the linux system we have solved the issue. I appreciate all comments it helped me to figure out where the problem first emerged.